# How join 2 table with calculation in the relation ID

Tags: sql-server, join

I'm using SQL Server 2012 for my RDBMS I have 3 main table `Tb_Template`,`Tb_Value`, and `Tb_Mapping`.

I use `Tb_Mapping` to join `Tb_Template` and `Tb_Value`. But the relation to `Tb_Value` have calculation `Val_Now` & `Val_Before`.

What I try is make `Value_ID` in `Tb_Mapping` is save query like this (example for ID 3 in `Tb_Mapping`)

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT Val_Now FROM Tb_Value WHERE ID = 'VAL4') + 
    (SELECT Val_Now FROM Tb_Value WHERE ID = 'VAL5')
```

Is there another way to make get result like `View_Result`

Table Tb_Template

```
ID    Description 
-----------------
1        Desc1    
2        Desc2        
3        Desc3        
4        Desc4    
5        Desc5
```

Table Tb_Value

```
ID    Val_Now    Val_Before 
----------------------------
VAL1     1            0
VAL2     5            3      
VAL3     1            1
VAL4     3            4
VAL5     0            2
```

Table Tb_Mapping

```
ID   Template_ID      Value_ID
-------------------------------
1       1               VAL1
2       2               VAL2      
3       3             VAL4+VAL5
4       4               VAL3
5       5        VAL1+VAL2-VAL4-VAL5
```

View_Result:

```
Description   Val_Now Val_Before
----------------------------------
   Desc1          1         0
   Desc2          5         3
   Desc3          3         6
   Desc4          1         1
   Desc5          3        -3
```

Comment: Does ALL calculations includes only additions and substractions? Is it possible to forbid parenthesis in an expression (i.e. not `(VAL1+VAL2)-(VAL4+VAL5)` but strictly `VAL1+VAL2-VAL4-VAL5`)?

Comment: @Akina yeah all calculation only additions and substractions, its possible to forbid parenthesis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
WITH cte AS (SELECT t.Description,
                    '+' + m.Value_ID Value_ID,
                    v.ID Val_ID,
                    v.Val_Now,
                    v.Val_Before
             FROM Tb_Template t
             JOIN Tb_Mapping m ON t.ID = m.Template_ID
             JOIN Tb_Value v ON CHARINDEX(v.ID, m.Value_ID) > 0)
SELECT Description,
       SUM( CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('+' + Val_ID, Value_ID) > 0
                 THEN Val_Now
                 WHEN CHARINDEX('-' + Val_ID, Value_ID) > 0
                 THEN -Val_Now
                 ELSE 0
                 END ) AS Val_Now,
       SUM( CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('+' + Val_ID, Value_ID) > 0
                 THEN Val_Before
                 WHEN CHARINDEX('-' + Val_ID, Value_ID) > 0
                 THEN -Val_Before
                 ELSE 0
                 END ) AS Val_Before
FROM cte
GROUP BY Description;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ce06798897be42581049a1544babf0f7) (parenthesis in mappings removed).

PS. None `Tb_Value.ID` value must be a prefix of another `Tb_Value.ID` value. If false then update CHARINDEX checking expression accordingly.

---

> oh maybe becase the VAL i have is VAL1 - VAL50 , because CHARINDEX() make the result like that ? example VAL9+VAL10 and the result VAL1,VAL9,VAL10 ? – Fikri

```sql
WITH cte AS (SELECT t.Description,
                    '+' + m.Value_ID + '+' Value_ID,
                    v.ID Val_ID,
                    v.Val_Now,
                    v.Val_Before
             FROM Tb_Template t
             JOIN Tb_Mapping m ON t.ID = m.Template_ID
             JOIN Tb_Value v ON CHARINDEX(v.ID, m.Value_ID) > 0)
SELECT Description,
       SUM( CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('+' + Val_ID + '+', Value_ID) + CHARINDEX('+' + Val_ID + '-', Value_ID) > 0
                 THEN Val_Now
                 WHEN CHARINDEX('-' + Val_ID + '+', Value_ID) + CHARINDEX('-' + Val_ID + '+', Value_ID) > 0
                 THEN -Val_Now
                 ELSE 0
                 END ) AS Val_Now,
       SUM( CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('+' + Val_ID + '+', Value_ID) + CHARINDEX('+' + Val_ID + '-', Value_ID) > 0
                 THEN Val_Before
                 WHEN CHARINDEX('-' + Val_ID + '+', Value_ID) + CHARINDEX('-' + Val_ID + '+', Value_ID) > 0
                 THEN -Val_Before
                 ELSE 0
                 END ) AS Val_Before
FROM cte
GROUP BY Description;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=84012196f4738e50e6d275a3c27c30cc)

Comment: What does this mean `'+' + m.Value_ID Value_ID`

Comment: See fiddle, look for a value of `Value_ID` column formed in CTE, compare with initial value. In main query the same operation is performed with `Val_ID` value for to know does the value must be added or substracted.

Comment: when i trying run in sql server `'+' + m.Value_ID Value_ID `  is get error message `The data types varchar and text are incompatible in the add operator.` its mean the data type Value_ID must be varchar ?

Comment: Use according CAST in CTE. `CAST(m.Value_ID AS CHAR)` instead of single `m.Value_ID`. But the best way is to alter column's datatype to VARCHAR with reasonable length - I doubt that your formulas are long enough for to use TEXT datatype.

Comment: After working with SQL Server for 20 years I can say that this design is going to be very painful if you ever get a moderately large amount of data in the tables. Take a step back and describe the data you are collecting and the result you are trying to output then we may be able to suggest a design that is a better fit for a relational database or alternatively another approach which is more viable.

comment intended to be friendly advice, at the end of the day you must decide

Comment: @Akina its work, but what if the `v.Val_Now`  and `v.Val_Before` data type is decimal ? i trying and the all result sum is 0.000000

Comment: @Mo64 i work with minimun info for get data from `Tb_Value` this is only data i can get

Comment: *what if the v.Val_Now and v.Val_Before data type is decimal ? i trying and the all result sum is 0.000000* Must work: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=960c04bad4243ee4892a0af69ab91e97 You did something wrongly...

Comment: @Akina when i try implement, and showing all field `cte` . Row when `Description` Desc3 have 3 row with 3 diffrent `Val_ID` with value VAL1,VAL4,VAL5 . and the rest is always have row with `Val_ID` value VAL1

Comment: @Fikri Create new fiddle - with your REAL structures and small sample data array, show desired result for this fiddle - will look at...

Comment: @Akina oh maybe becase the VAL i have is VAL1 - VAL50 , because  `CHARINDEX()` make the result like that ? example VAL9+VAL10 and the result VAL1,VAL9,VAL10 ?

Comment: @Fikri *maybe becase the VAL i have is VAL1 - VAL50* [censored]!!! Read answer's postscript one more lot of times.

Comment: @Akina yeah sorry, i know where the mistake, thanks a lot

Comment: @Fikri Updated, check.